# Get Facebook Ads Insights results in pandas dataframe error

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am converting a set of Facebook AD APIs to pandas dataframe. They are in facebook adInsights  format(facebook_business.api.Cursor).

I went through the solution I went through the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34092054/how-to-parse-nested-fb-api-response-from-python-sdk/36397567#36397567) of converting it to a list first and then using pd.Dataframe, but I am getting Facebook Bad Object error -

```
FacebookBadObjectError: Bad data to set object data
```

Unable to recognize why this is happening and if there is another way to convert the APIs to a dataframe?